# MVC 3 Like Remote attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I nead function like Remote attribute but not for validation but to update other field example:

```
public class MyModel
{
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public string Surname{get;set;}

  [RemoteUpdate("Name,Surname")]
  public string FullName{get{return Name + " " + Surname}}
}
```

In this case `FullName` will be only a label where. When someone focuses out of the `Name` and `Surname` field I want `FullName` to be Updated.

Is this possible?

Comment: You have the server side code confused with the client side operations.  Functionality like this would need to live in javascript. If you created the attribute it would be writing javascript to the page.

Comment: i need base on attribute to be generate javascript that will do that. sorry if i was not so clear.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to implement this completely on the client side using javascript.

Here is a really basic example for this using jQuery:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        Name:
        <input id="name" type="text"/>
        Surname:
        <input id="surname" type="text"/>
        <span id="fullname"></span>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
         $('#surname, #name').keyup(function() { $('#fullname').text($('#name').val() + ' ' + $('#surname').val()); });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

The `keyup` event updates the span tag on every key stroke. If you want to update it only on leaving the textbox you can use the `change` event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either a jQuery .ajax() call or .get() operations when your client side textboxes loses focus (ie blurs) to then call your remote URL to do whatever you need. I didn't pass any parameters into the get request here (you can) and of course this is a generic example - but the idea is here on how you would do your remote call

```
 <input id="surname" type="text"/>
 <input id="fullname" type="text"/>

<script>
$('#surname').blur(function() {
 $.get('remotefunctions/index', function(data) {
   $('#fullname').html(data);
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ok I was not so clear base on attribute i need to generate javascript that will call serverside code Controller and update fullname.